# Term for a Set Equipped With a Binary Operation Which Contains Inverses

Tags: group-theory, definition, semigroups, magma, quasigroups

Let $A$ be a set and let $\circ:A\times A\rightarrow B,$ $A\subseteq B$ be a binary operation ($A$ is not necessarily closed under $\circ$). If there exists some unique $e\in A$ such that $e\circ a=a\circ e=a$ for all $a\in A$ and for all $a\in A,$ there exists some unique $b\in A$ such that $a\circ b=b\circ a=e.$ Is there a name for $(A,\circ)?$
$$$$
Essentially, A is a group without the requirement that A be closed under the operation.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2725786/104041)

Comment: Do you also want to add some form of associativity? (That's an important part of group-ness.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes

Answer (score 2):

That table in Wikipedia is helpful:
[group-like structures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)#Classification_by_properties).

So your object could be called a [groupoid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid), if we consider the binary operation as a partial operation $B \times B \rightarrow B$. (Although this is larger than your definition, because in most cases the set of pairs for which the operation is defined cannot be expressed as $A \times A$).

Unfortunately, there are more than one definition for groupoid, as explained in various places, e.g.
[on Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Groupoid.html).

Note that the combination of non-closedness with associativity is tricky: you have to state whether $a \circ (b \circ c) = (a \circ b) \circ c$ means "when both sides are defined, they are equal", or "when at least one side is defined, the other side is also defined and equal".

A well-known example of groupoid is the fundamental groupoid, in algebraic topology.